# Create "login with Facebook" but the response is "Failed when attempting to obtain access token"

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to log in from facebook on my site in symfony, I've added app id and secret, and I've added the address between the valid OAuth redirect URIs. Despite this, when I try to log in, I get the following response from Facebook:

```
 ('8', 'Undefined index: auth', '/var/www/html/home/focsivcontest/website/src/Module/SecurityBundle/Listener/DCSOpauthEventSubscriber.php', '39', array('event' => object(OpauthResponseEvent), 'responseData' => array('error' => array('provider' => 'facebook', 'code' => 'access_token_error', 'message' => 'Failed when attempting to obtain access token', 'raw' => 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate x-fb-rev: 3210881 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 x-fb-trace-id: G4paDe7A0d1 facebook-api-version: v2.4 Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT Vary: Accept-Encoding X-FB-Debug: iSRLkFs3WO9P9JWmtz29QuUjgpqnAy/memfu6GFByhk2T6Lj0EEklHWDJYQhlc1bKb454w4DGg98ojQp1Ea1gw== Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 21:23:26 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 239'), 'timestamp' => '2017-08-08T23:23:26+02:00')))
```

Can someone help me?

In my twig i have:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-info" href="{{ url('dcs_opauth_connect', {'strategy' : 'facebook'}) }}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook-square"></i> {{ 'button.login_with_facebook'|trans({}, 'ModuleSecurityBundle') }}</a>
```

My DSCOpauthEventSubscriber:

```
public function checkCredentials(OpauthResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $responseData = $event->getResponseData();

        $provider = $responseData['auth']['provider'];
        $uid = $responseData['auth']['uid'];

        if (null !== $oauthToken = $this->oauthTokenManager->findByProviderAndUid($provider, $uid)) {
            $event->setAuthenticate(false);
            $this->tokenService->createFromUser($oauthToken->getUser());
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    public function createOauthToken(OpauthResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $responseData = $event->getResponseData();
        $email = $responseData['auth']['info']['email'];

        if (empty($email)) {
            return;
        }

        if (null === $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email)) {
            return;
        }

        $oauthToken = $this->oauthTokenManager->create();
        $oauthToken->setUser($user);
        $oauthToken->setProvider($responseData['auth']['provider']);
        $oauthToken->setUid($responseData['auth']['uid']);

        $this->oauthTokenManager->save($oauthToken);
        $this->tokenService->createFromUser($user);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to call Facebook auth. You can remove the id and secret.

Comment: What API version are you using, what version of the PHP SDK (I assume this gets embedded as an external library)?